# getting output of second row from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have this mysql statement without limit so it will get first row in ascending order but i want to get the title of second row as well

```
    $res = mysql_query("select * from tas where id='{$m_id}' ");
```

after that i can fetch and get the first output without any issue earlier i was required to get the id so i used this

```
   $nidf=$m_id-1;
```

but now i need title of previous id.table consists if id,title,views etc  .i know it can be done easily by this query

```
    $res2 = mysql_query("select * from tas where id='{$nidf}' ");
```

but i dont want to execute second syl query and i want to learn how it can be done without using above query

i cant not use while as i need only second title and rest of the thigs i need for first row only

Comment: Leave mysql, it is deprecated. Join PDO : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM tas
WHERE id <= $m_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

fetch all the rows that have your specified ID **OR* LESS**, order by that id in descending order, then return only the first 2 rows in that ordered set. That'll be the $m_id you wanted, and the next immediately lower id as well.

Comment: i am using $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); and after that $output=$row['title'];  which will give output of first row how to get for second row